# OpenCV SVM training dataset

Tags: opencv, dataset, computer-vision, svm, training-data

Lets say I have a dataset of about 350 positive images and more than 400 negative images. They aren't the same size. Also their size is bigger than 640x320.

1. What should I do to create a better dataset? Do I need the images to be smaller? If yes, why?
2. Should I apply some normalization to the dataset? What should it be (contrast, noise reduction)?
3. Can I create a bigger dataset using the existing one? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. What is the unit of "better dataset"? Images need not be smaller, they may be. 2. You may or may not. 3. You may or may not. You see, it all depends on what sort of data you're working on.

Comment: you must isolate the objects of those images, so that the only basically presents only the object, centered and of same size in each image. There should be some background, but not too much. So normally it is NOT enough to have 500 images where there is the object "somewhere" in that image. For size you should choose the minimum size that you want to detect or that is detectable. Have a look at INRIA human database, they provide "original images" and "normalized training datasets", so you can get an impression: http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/data/human/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Optimal size of images is that you can easily classify object by
   yourself.
2. Yes, classifiers works better after normalization, there are
   options. Most popular ways is center dataset (subtract mean) and normalize range of
   values say in [-1:1] range. Other popular way of normalization is similar to previous but normalize standard deviation (preferable in most cases).
3. Yes, you can create bigger dataset from existing on by adding
   distorsions and noise to your images from existing dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to ask you some questions if it is not a problem. What do you actually mean by "classify object by yourself"? My dataset is images. What do you mean by "normalize range of values"?

Comment: "Classyfy objects by youself" I meant look at object image and decide which class it belongs. If you able to classify it, try to reduce image sample size and try again. If you can classify object, then image contains all necessary information for classification. Normalization in the case of image classification is pixel values normalization or histogram normalization, also sometimes is useful to subtract mean image form every image in DS first. Then apply pixel normalization.

Comment: Pixel normalization performed on a set of pixels with the same coordinates which belongs to different images in the dataset. 
For example you notmalize a set of pixes with coordinates (10,10).
First you find mean of all these pixels (it will belong to mean image), subtract the mean from each pixel value, then normalize standard deviation of the set (or normalize the range of pixels values on  the set).

Comment: Do you have a suggestions what distortions should I use?

Comment: The simpliest case are small affine transforms. 
There was patch generator in OpenCV, I don't know where is it now in recent versions (hope it is still in features2d.hpp) but this link could help you: http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classcv_1_1PatchGenerator.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at INRIA dataset and their comments of how they "normalized" their input images for HoG person detection training.

http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/data/human/

one thing that wasn't mentioned yet is the fact, that for most detection techniques it isn't enough to collect a set of n images with the desired object "somewhere" within that image. Instead you should crop that image around the object (with some border).

e.g. for person detection they used this input image:

[image]

but they cropped and rescaled (and transformed) those regions (objects):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

probably there are some good hints about training in the thesis too:
http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/dalal/NavneetDalalThesis.pdf